# spin: Could not dial http client, please ensure Gate is running

Tags: spinnaker

Do you know why I am getting the following error?

I have tried to `port-forward 8080 and also 8084`.

```
spin application save --application-name sample \
                        --owner-email example@example.com \
                        --cloud-providers kubernetes \
                        --gate-endpoint http://localhost:8084/gate
Could not dial http client, please ensure Gate is running. Failing.
dial tcp: lookup tcp/8084/gate: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

All the pods is running:

```
cd-install-using-hal-r4ssx          0/1       Completed   0          22h
cd-redis-master-0                   1/1       Running     0          22h
cd-spinnaker-halyard-0              1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-clouddriver-77bf675c75-h847f   1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-deck-67d875cd75-6ptdp          1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-echo-8c9cb6d9d-nhf49           1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-front50-549749dcd4-d82pg       1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-gate-59645db6b-8r78g           1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-igor-6c6d99499f-f76z2          1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-orca-66c79f6dc-9wm4c           1/1       Running     0          22h
spin-rosco-5bc54c8d67-xrb9p         1/1       Running     0          22h
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this issue? thx

Comment: No, I had to let it go for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forwarded the port 9000 instead of 8084 and changed the `--gate-endpoint http://localhost:9000/gate` and it worked.

```
export DECK_POD=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "cluster=spin-deck" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")

kubectl port-forward --namespace default $DECK_POD 9000:9000
```

Comment: Cool, I will have a look tomorrow